# Run PSEXEC process in ASP.NET as different user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, psexec

I'm trying to connect from my ASP web application published on IIS server to some servers using psExec, start application and get the output.

When I try to start process without setting credentials I get this error:

> Access is denied

but if I do the same as administrator, I'm only getting empty fields for output, errors and exception variables. Also, when I do it from my local pc using visual studio it works properly.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
try
        {
           Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
            p.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Monitoring\bin\PsExec.exe";
                server = "dp-next.b42";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = @" \\" + server + " \"c:\\program files\\omniback\\bin\\omnirpt.exe\" -report list_sessions -timeframe 12 12";
            p.StartInfo.UserName = "admin";
            p.StartInfo.Domain = "domain";

            string pass = "password";
            SecureString s = new SecureString();
            foreach(char c in pass)
            {
                s.AppendChar(c);
            }
            p.StartInfo.Password = s;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.Start();
            output = output + p.ProcessName;
            //output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            while ((res = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                i++;
                output = output + res;
            }

            errors = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            p.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exe = ex.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had to develop something very similar. Here is what I did.

Instead of using:

```
p.StartInfo.UserName = "admin";
p.StartInfo.Domain = "domain";
p.StartInfo.Password = s;
```

I put username and password directly inside PsExec command arguments (respectively with `-u` and `-p`). In your case:

```
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = @" \\" + server + " -u YOUR_DOMAIN\\YOUR_USERNAME -p YOUR_PASSWORD \"c:\\program files\\omniback\\bin\\omnirpt.exe\" -report list_sessions -timeframe 12 12";
```

More info on PsExec usage [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).